# warbler doesn't packages a standalone application in a jar file but instead in a war file

Tags: jar, jruby, warbler

I've a JRuby-based standalone application with the following structure:

```
my_app
  - bin
    - my_app      # that's a launcher script
  - lib
    - my_app.rb
```

And when I **warble** in the top level directory, it doesn't generates a jar file as expected but instead a generates a war file. And this war, as expected, follows the war file's standard structure.

I've followed the documentation to do it:

https://github.com/nicksieger/warbler

"If your project do not have a .gemspec, Warbler will attempt
to guess the launcher from the contents of the bin directory
and use the lib directory as the lone require path. All files
in the project will be included in the archive."

Anyone already did it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is in version 1.3.0 which unfortunately hasn't been released yet. Try the prerelease version on rubygems.org (`gem install warbler --pre`).